# Altair combining multiple data sets ( one my uploaded, another Altair)

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, altair

im started to enjoy Altair plotting and i found their One Dot Per Zip map and i kinda have an interest to combine Altair long/lat/zips with my own pandas dataframe containing zips but i dont know how.
Where should i start?

```
            source = data.zipcodes.url
            # source = filtered_df
            chart = alt.Chart(source).transform_calculate(
                "leading digit", alt.expr.substring(alt.datum.zip_code, 0, 1)
            ).mark_circle(size=3).encode(
                longitude='longitude:Q',
                latitude='latitude:Q',
                color='leading digit:N',
                tooltip='zip_code:N'
            ).project(
                type='albersUsa'
            ).properties(
                width=1250,
                height=1000
            )
            st.altair_chart(chart)
```

Which is fine as it uses Altair data set, but how can i mix long/lat/zips with my own data ? If i change source to my own filtered_df - it wont read Altairs long/lat as source is not Altair anymore.
Thank You.

Tried changing

`source = data.zipcodes.url` to `source = filtered_df` but source is changed ant nothing is shown any more which is Understandable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ensure that your dataframe has columns for latitude and longitude corresponding to each zip code. Maybe find a dataset that provides these info. Then you can merge the dataframe with latitude and longitude data on the zip code field. Once your datafram (`filtered_df`) has the necessary info, you can use it as the source in your Altair chart like what you've written, replacing `data.zipcodes.url` with your dataframe.

some example for your reference on how you might want to merge the datasets:

```
# Your dataframe with zip codes
your_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'zip_code': [...],
    # ... other columns ...
})

# DataFrame with zip codes and their corresponding latitude and longitude
zip_lat_lon_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'zip_code': [...],
    'latitude': [...],
    'longitude': [...],
})

# Merge the dataframes on the zip code column
filtered_df = pd.merge(your_df, zip_lat_lon_df, on='zip_code', how='left')

# Now filtered_df contains zip codes along with the corresponding latitude and longitude
```

Try this out I hope it works for you.